# Is gesture recogniser not work in Xamarin.Forms Slider?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have added TapGestureRecogniser for Xamarin.Forms.Slider as like below. But the gesture not recognised if I tap the slider. I have checked in Xamarin.Forms.iOS only.

```
var slider = new Slider()
{
    InputTransparent = false,
    Margin = 20
};
slider.Value = 20;
slider.Maximum = 100;
slider.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer()
{
    NumberOfTapsRequired = 1,
    Command = new Command(() => 
    {
       // Not fired this command if I tap the slider...                 
    })
});
```

Even I have tried by adding margin too as like in the below solution, but still not works for me.
[Xamarin.Forms Slider iOS gesture failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432446/xamarin-forms-slider-ios-gesture-failure)

Even I have tried by loading the slider inside content view and that too not works. Please suggest better solution for me.

Comment: Check this: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/53107/tapgesturerecognizer-on-slider

Comment: @SelvarathinamVinoch, If I host the slider inside any view like ContentView, then I can able to handle the touch for the parent view. Here, ContentView. But I need to handle the touch directly for the Slider.